# Meteor: How to remove imported scss for multiple layout

Tags: meteor, sass, flow-router

I am working on `Meteor 1.4` with `flow-router` and I have to multiple layout templates.

**Route `/site/template1` loads**

```
BlazeLayout.render('Template1', {
  main: 'All_Schools'
});

Template.Template1.onCreated(function () {
  import '../styles/template1.scss';
});
```

**Route `/site/template2` loads**

```
BlazeLayout.render('Template2', {
  main: 'All_Schools'
});

Template.Template2.onCreated(function () {
  import '../styles/template2.scss';
});
```

The problem is.. `template1` and `template2` has template link in UI (`so no hard reload`). if the user changes the templates. the cached scss styles affect new style. How to remove imported scss file `onDestroy`? or should I want to change my approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a bit differently. There aren't any advantages to loading your styles in your Template like this, since Meteor does not currently support code-splitting. I would instead recommend that you keep your styles separate from your Templates, then have each one of your Templates wrapped in a top level class selector, that can be used to control the styles for each specific Template.

For example, you could store all of your styles in a `/imports/ui/stylesheets` directory, breaking them up however you want:

```
/imports/ui/stylesheets/template1.scss
/imports/ui/stylesheets/template2.scss
...
```

You would then reference all of these stylesheets once on your `/client/main.scss` file to have them loaded, like:

```
@import "{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/template1.scss";
@import "{}/imports/ui/stylesheets/template2.scss";
...
```

Your individual Templates would be wrapped in top level class selectors like:

**template1.html**

```
<template name="template1">
  <div class="template1">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Then your styles for each Template can be wrapped in a matching top level selector like:

**/imports/ui/stylesheets/template1.scss**

```
.template1 {
  .some-class1 {
    ...
  }
  .some-class2 {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This way you can fully separate out your styles for each component (as needed) but still be able to leverage style inheritance.